# Point Distance Tool not licensed errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity, license

I've some problems concerning Point Distance in ArcGIS 10.5. 
 Whenever I try it to open, this tool appeared "require licensed tools".

Comment: The [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/point-distance.htm) states that an Advanced license is required. What license level do you have available?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.